# what is the use of console functions in c

Tags: c

i have used turbo c++ and commands like ***gotoxy*** works absolutely fine with no initialization. I can straight away use them whereas in Code::Blocks in need to mess around a little and create a function which i call later on in main function.

but can someone explain this fucntion:

```
#include <windows.h>

COORD coord= {0,0};   \\ Q1) What does this COORD means? What kind of data type is this?

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
coord.X=x;            
coord.Y=y;
SetConsoleCursorPostion(GetStdHandle(Std_Output_Handle(),coord); 
/*What does this last line code mean? SetConsoleCursorPosition? Please explain each & every word of this line : GetStdHandle?? What does this Handle do?*/
}
```

After searching about console functions and structures i found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

Will it be helpful in C? Should i read and learn all of these?

Comment: It is used to override previous emitted data on the console. (for instance if you print the percentage of done computations, you sometimes want to update this. Cordinates are normally `(Row,Column)`

Comment: @CommuSoft that is very less information can you elaborate your answer? What is console here in C?

Comment: A console is a group of three streams every program has, the `stdin` to read input (for instance if you use pipes), `stdout` to write data to and `stderr` to write error information to.

Comment: @CommuSoft: `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are input and output streams that may be associated with just about anything, not necessarily with a console. For example, `some_program <input.txt >output.txt` connects `stdin` and `stdout` to files (both on Windows and on UNIX-like systems).

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're right - pipes were for instances mentioned in the comment. I was merely giving the right direction about what a console is supposed to be since some people don't know anything about shell/tty/...

Comment: Use `ncurses library` It's freesoftware and very powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mentioned functions are Windows API functions and are well documented in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/).

[COORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a structure to hold screen COORDinates X and Y.
[GetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns a handle to standard device (input, output, or error). A **handle** is an index in system table which gives access to the Windows kernel object.
Std_Output_Handle() I suppose returns the STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE value to specify std output,
active console buffer. [SetControlCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sets the cursor position (obviously).

"Will it be helpful in C?" - if you use them in your project on Windows, almost sure.
There is nothing bad in using Windows API functions, imho. They are well documented and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

SetConsoleCursor set cursor to specified place in console that depends on cord.x and cord.y.
GetstdHandle()  gets handle for handle that handle printing characters into console. The second  parameters is coordinates of the new position of the cursor.
If you have declared this function, you can normally use gotoxy(x,y) and It would be work fine. Coord is structer:

```
typedef struct _COORD {
     SHORT X; 
     SHORT Y;
}COORD, *PCOORD;
```